# How to write a regular expression with a list of quotes, using raw string literal?

Tags: python, string, literals, raw

The main idea of raw string literal, as they wrote here, is to avoid the excessive number of backslases.
The main idea of regular expressions is to make a search for substring clear.
This is why I use regular expressions and raw string literal.
Please help me write a regular expression that contains a list of quotes.

```
rexp = '\\$\\{[\\\\\\w]+\\(.*\\)\\[["\'`]\\]\\}'
print(rexp, len(rexp))

rexp1 = r'\$\{[\\\w]+\(.*\)\[["\'`]\]\}'
print(rexp1, len(rexp1))
```

```
\$\{[\\\w]+\(.*\)\[["'`]\]\} 28
\$\{[\\\w]+\(.*\)\[["\'`]\]\} 29
```

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Did you try that yourself?  The output contains two backslashes.  I don't understand your comment...

Comment: @JohnGordon Right, pardon me. This works correct only for normal strings.

Comment: There is _no_ method to include a backslash at the end of a raw string literal. However, you can have one at the end of a regular string literal: `"foo\\"`. If you really want to use a raw string for other reasons, append a regular string to it: `r"foo\bar\baz" + "\\"`.